# Cypher creates number as a long. How do I create an integer?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a problem with types in Neo4j. I am trying with the following query to create a node with a variable number with the integer value 1:

```
Create (n:Test{numer:1})
```

When I am getting the node from the Java api I am getting an error telling me that it is of type long.

How can I see of what type a variable is saved in Neo4J? How can I save an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Cypher or REST API then Neo4j (internally) use Java's Long for integer values and Java's Double for floating point values.

In Java API you can use following datatypes

- boolean
- byte
- short
- int
- long
- float
- double
- char
- String

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/property-values-detailed.html

Comment: Ok, so Integers do not exist then?