# Neo4j load long (data type) values from csv (string values)

Tags: csv, neo4j, long-integer

I have a csv file like this

```
user_id|article_id
1254265488752|7524613
455751657522|2546387
```

And I want to lod this csv to my graph. But I don't found any way that I could load `user_id` property as `long` data type. For int there is `toInt()` function but for `long`?

I think that comparing numbers is faster than comparing strings. Am I right or not? If that doesn't matter I'm fine with loding `user_id` as `string`.

Answer (score 2):

According to this question, data is stored as JAVA long internally if you use `toInt()` in Cypher: [Cypher creates number as a long. How do I create an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999835/cypher-creates-number-as-a-long-how-do-i-create-an-integer)

This works:

```
CREATE (n:Test)
SET n.long = toInt('21474836472344534')
RETURN n
```